# Asking for up vote for accepting the answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

I have given answer to a user's question and he commented that it is working fine, and said that "after up-voting question I will accept your answer!!!".

In such situation what should I do? (He then deleted his comment.)

Comment: Nothing. You do nothing.

Comment: @Lucifer do I need to report someone?

Comment: you are at right place at present :)

Comment: A user is not required to accept. So please be patient.  (I has one answer that took the OP 3 years to accept). And if they don't they don't, just continue to give great answers.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe no this got nothing to do about commenting on accept rate.

Comment: Assuming that you didn't ask the OP to accept your answer (that's not an appropriate use for the comments), flag for moderator attention.  We'd be happy to leave a comment to the effect that what they're doing isn't appropriate, or take stronger measures, if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that user is plain rude. Nothing more, nothing less.

I would have posted a comment back saying "Sorry, this is not how this site works".

It goes without saying, you should never give up to such bullying; upvote a post only if it deserves it, not as part of negotiation.